# Big O notation of Formula - P *R Squared

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-science

I want to calcuate the Big O notation for an area of circle.I wonder what is the time complexity of Pi *r^2? is it O(n) or O(n^2)? Please also check if my way of doing is correct.

```
 Algorithm
   Step 1: Start //  f(n)=O(1)  ( Executes 1 time)
   Step 2: Get an integer input from user for AREA and RADIUS//. f(n)=O(n)=O(1) ( Executes 1 time)
   Step 3: Print the statement "Enter the Radius of Circle: //f(n)=O(n)=O(1) ( Executes 1 time)
    Step 4: Calculate the area of the circle using the formula of  
    //f(n)=O(n)=?
    (r - Radius) //f(n)=O(n)=O(1) ( Executes 1 time)
    
   Step 5: Print the statement "Area of Circle:" //f(n)=O(n)=O(1) ( Executes 1 time)
    
   Step 6: Print Area//f(n)=O(n)=O(1) ( Executes 1 time)
    
   Step 7: Stop //f(n)=O(n)=O(1) ( Executes 1 time)
    
    f(n)=O(n)=?
```

Comment: Big O ?  do you mean area? as that is what your calculation should give as a result. Or do you mean Big O = circumference?

Comment: i edited the question.Sorry for the typo. It should big O notation. I am confused about whether big O notation for the formula should be pi*r^2 is O(n) or O(n^2)?

Comment: it's neither: it's O(1): the complexity is constant regardless of the size of r

Comment: *"Please also [...]"* -- there is a limit of one question per question (and open-ended "is this correct" questions are off-topic here).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know , i deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your model of computation.
For most practical purposes its `O(1)`, because the runtime does not depend on your input `r`. This assumes implicitly that your input is bounded, for example fits into a 32-bit integer.

More theoretical you can think about arbitrary big `r`. The `N` in the big O notation then is normally the length (number of bits) of `r` and not the size of the number. Here you cant assume that you can multiply any two numbers in `O(1)` but it will depend on the length of the numbers.

In this case you would get `O(N^2)` with a naive multiplying algorithm, which can be improved to `O(N log N)` with more advanced techniques. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Computational_complexity_of_multiplication .